# Video sharing with thumbnail and play button, using UIActivityViewController in ios7?

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

Want to share video using UIActivityViewController with its thumbnail and playbutton icon.

I used .mp4 url but facebook shows url not thumbnail.
how to make possible to show video(thumbnail with play button) on Facebook without using following code, because it doesnt work.

```
     ALAsset * asset = [[ALAsset alloc] init];
     [asset setVideoAtPath:urlToVideoFile completionBlock:NULL];
     NSArray * activityItems = @[asset];
     UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have put is adding asset into array, don't put asset directly instead put url and try.